# How to add a class if repeater equals something

Tags: angularjs

If I have a paginator like so:

```
<ul class="pagination" ng-repeat="n in ProductCount">
    <li class="active"><a ng-click="Paginate( n )"  href="#"><% n %> <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to have the `class="active"` if `n == 1`, how do I add this kind of expression in?

I would assume that when I run the Paginate function, I can pass the current element in and then change the class with jquery... but on load, I want the first item to be active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the documentation for [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). You specify a map of class names to boolean expressions.

```
<li ng-class="{active: n == 1}"></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `li` apply:

`ng-class="{active: n==1}"`